# Direct SSH from Mac to Raspberry Pi on its own wifi

Tags: ssh, ethernet, setup, headless, macos

I'm as new as possible to Raspberry Pi, and I'd like to configure the following:

- My Raspberry Pi connected directly to my Mac via an Ethernet (or
  other) cable, so that I can setup and run the RP entirely from 
  my Mac via SSH.
- My Raspberry Pi connected *simultaneously* to the
  Internet through its own independent connection (e.g., via 
  a wifi dongle) on a different network (I have two) from that 
  used by the Mac.

Ideally I'd like to be able to accomplish this "headlessly" (if that's a word): starting out of the box with the Raspberry Pi, plugging it in to the Mac, and going from there. I do not want to RP to have any access to the network that the Mac is using: the connections to the RP from the Mac should be "one way".

Is there a way to accomplish this? This (for a variety of reasons) is the *only* (well, [not quite only](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/38851/570), but that way won't work for me) way I can use the Raspberry Pi, so I'm hoping it can be done!

---

OS X 10.11.1; RP 2 B v1.1

Comment: Unless you are less cryptic, and detail the networks and how they are interconnected, no one can tell.

Comment: @Milliways: Separate networks entirely.